# Try to run CouchDB on Local Network

Tags: iphone, macos, couchdb, local

I have installed CouchDB via MacPorts and CouchDB is starting up every time when I start my Mac.

```
sudo launchctl load -w /opt/local/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.couchdb.plist
```

So on `http://localhost:5984 everything works fine.`

I have downloaded the  grocery-sync demo App from couchDB sources. And when I type in the address of a CouchDB Service the App works fine and communicate with the couchDB Service.
In my case the CouhchDB Service is cloudant.

I'm using  `https://username:password@username.cloudant.com/grocery-sync/`

But if I try to communicate with my local machine via WiFi, the App doesn't work.

I'm using `http://username:password@username.<ipAddressOfMyMacInWifi>:5984/grocery-sync/`

Do I have to configure something? Must I use the Server App for Mavericks?

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", can you be more specific here? Is there an error message, and if so, what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with gaige but one other thing to check.  CouchDB uses 127.0.0.1 by default which doesn't bind to external interfaces.  You need to change it to bind to 0.0.0.0.  Go to `http://localhost:5984/_utils`, click Configuration, look for bind_address and change it to 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Based on the minimal information here, you don't want `@username.<ipaddressofmymacinwifi>:5984`, you likely want `@<ipaddressofmymacinwifi>:5984`.  You already put the username in the `http` URL at `username:password` and putting it after the `@` is going to attempt to use the hostname `username.192.168.0.1` if your IP address is 192.168.0.1, which will not resolve correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

I have modified the `bind_address` variable in config view of CouchDB.

And the Database URL is   `username.password@<ipaddressofmymacinwifi:5984/grocery-sync/`

Its working now perfectly